# Inheritance likelihood of SNVs vs InDels

Tags: genetics, cancer

Suppose you have identified a couple of variants in a tumour sample. One of them is a **deletion** and the other is an **SNV** in the same gene. You have a familial history of prostate cancer and other cancers. The germline testing results are several weeks away but in the meantime how would you decide which one of them is inherited and which is somatic. They both could be somatic or inherited but for sake of curiosity let's consider they are different.

Comment: I don’t understand the question - are you asking whether there is a difference whether SNPs or indels occur on germline or somatic cells?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Thank you for taking the [tour], please also go through the [help] pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and [edit] your question accordingly. In particular, your question: 1) isn't clear, 2) is overly broad, and 3) shows no evidence of prior research. Details: 2) among other things you haven't specified what gene(s) you are interested in. 3) you haven't said where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Please note all of these are reasons for down-voting and closure.